# How to set node as a parameter using pointer in LinkedList?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

There are two functions in Linkedin: insert_first and testLinkedList_inser_first.
The structures are shown below.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct ColumInfo {
    char name[MAX_LENGTH];
    char phone[MAX_LENGTH];
}ColumInfo;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ColumInfo columinfo;
    struct ListNode* pNext;
}ListNode;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The insert_first function looks like this

```
ListNode* insertFirst(ListNode* head, ColumInfo value) {
    ListNode* added = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    strcpy(added->columinfo.name, value.name);
    strcpy(added->columinfo.phone, value.phone);
    added->pNext = head;

    head = added;

    return added;
}
```

The testLinkedList_insertFirst function is shown below.
The testLinkedList_insertFirst function takes *node and nNum as parameters and measures the time it takes to execute the insert function nNum times.

```
double testLinkedList_insertFirst(ListNode* node, int nNum) {
    clock_t start = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < nNum; ++i) {
        char name[MAX_LENGTH] = "samyoahri";
        char phone[MAX_LENGTH] = "010-xxxx-xxxx";

        sprintf(name, "samyoahri: %d", i);
        sprintf(phone, "010-xxxx-xxxx: %d", i);

        ColumInfo data;
        strcpy(data.name, name);
        strcpy(data.phone, phone);

        node = insertFirst(node, data);
        //printList(node);
        //printf("==============\n");
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    return (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

However, the insert_first function is returning the node correctly. However, the testLinkedList_insertFirst function returns the double value correctly, but when I want to update the node using call by reference, the testLinkedList function does not work correctly.
How can I solve this?
Below, you can see that the node is updated correctly in the testLinkedList_insertFirst function.
However, in the main statement, you can see that the nodes are not updated correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojCO8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lihbb.png)

link: https://github.com/samyoahri/PhoneBook

I tried to update parameter using malloc, pointer.

Comment: OT: There's just no need for `#pragma pack` for your structures. Who told you to use that? What is their reason for it?

Comment: On another couple of notes, you don't need the `strcpy` calls in the `insertFirst` function. It's possible to assign between structures. So `added->columninfo = value` would work just as well. And in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (or any function returning a `void *` pointer). And in `testLinkedList_insertFirst`, why don't you `sprintf` directly into the `data` elements? There's no need for the temporary `name` and `phone` variables.

Comment: The reason for using the #pragma is for maximum memory efficiency.

Comment: Lastly for what I ***guess*** the problem is: In the `testLinkedList_insertFirst` function you modify the *local* variable `node`. The function that calls `testLinkedList_insertFirst` will not see those changes. I recommend you do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*. Or simply change the return of the function to return the new head node.

Comment: OT: why are you experiencing problems with a linked list (beginner problem), yet you've got pointless code regarding timing? Focus on learning one thing at a time...

Comment: "Memory efficiency" is a red herring, especially for a case like that. The compiler will create structures with padding because it will actually be *more* "efficient" as the structures and members will have better alignment. You might not even save any bytes, only make your code worse.

Comment: `head = added;` has no effect outside `insertFirst`. You need to take in a pointer to the pointer for that to make sense. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/oMqzfxWco)

Comment: "Memory efficiency"?!?! Your program will contain `"samyoahri: %d"` AND `"samyoahri"` AND `"010-xxxx-xxxx: %d"` AND `"010-xxxx-xxxx"`!! How is that _efficient_ in regard to memory?

Comment: I'm aware of the inefficiency of the temporary character array and will fix it.
I also fully understand that not using pragmas is efficient for the compiler, and I appreciate the new knowledge.

But what I want to ask is, is there any way to update node in the main statement by calling node by reference in testLinkedList_insertFirst?

Comment: Why does your question have code to *time* the execution, when you have an incorrectly working function? Please focus your question on the problem, and remove the noise of the timing -- which is irrelevant to your problem. Instead provide a simple usecase where you provide input and output and point out how the output is not as expected. Also, code and debugging information should not be provided as an image, but as text.

Answer (score 0):

The `linkedList1` or `linkedList2` variable in `main()` cannot be set on return from the function `testLinkedList_insertFirst()` unless the code either 1. returns a pointer to a structure from within the function or 2. passes the address of the `LinkedList1` or `LinkedList2` variables from `main()` so that the `testLinkedList_insertFirst()` function receives a double pointer as a function parameter.

Method 1: You can return the clocks elapsed as well as the pointer to the created linked list from the `testLinkedList_insertFirst()` function via a pointer to structure allocated on the heap:

```
typedef struct {
    double clockpassed;
    ListNode * chain;
} ret_type ;
...
...
...
ret_type * testLinkedList_insertFirst(int nNum) {

  clock_t start = clock();
  ListNode * node;
  ret_type * retvals;
  retvals = malloc (sizeof(ret_type));

  for (int i = 0; i < nNum; ++i) {
   ...
   ...
     node = insertFirst(node, data);
  }
 
  clock_t end = clock();
  retvals->clockpassed = (double) (end - start);
  retvals->chain = node;
  return retvals;
}
```

In the above code passing `ListNode *` parameter to the function `testLinkedList_insertFirst()` can be eliminated, as the modified code is anyway returning the linked list from the structure allocated within the function. In `main()` you can then access the linked list thus:

```
void main() {
   ...
   ...
   ListNode* linkedList = NULL;
   ret_type *pMain_ret =NULL ;
   pMain_ret = testLinkedList_insertFirst(nNum);
   linkedList = pMain_ret->chain;
   ListNode * processNext = linkedList;
   for (int i=0; i<nNum; i++) {
        printf("%s ", processNext->columinfo.name);
        processNext=processNext->pNext;
   }
   ...
   ...
}
```

Method 2: Pass the `linkedList1` or `linkedList2` variable in `main()` as a double pointer parameter:

```
...
...
double testLinkedList_insertFirst(ListNode** node, int nNum) {
 clock_t start = clock();
 for (int i = 0; i < nNum; ++i) {
     ...
     ...
     *node = insertFirst(*node, data);
 }
 clock_t end = clock();
 return (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
void main() {
  ...
  ...
   ListNode* linkedList = NULL;
   printf("insertFirst: %.3f\n", testLinkedList_insertFirst(&linkedList, nNum));
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Needless to say, you will have to take care to free the linked list nodes in `main()` at the end of the program.